# No caves found after digging a large area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A friend and I dug down to diamond level and began a quarry. We both went different ways, and after about an hour we each had massive quarries dug out. However neither of us had found a cave. I heard cave noises in a corner so we dug in all directions, still no caves. I know I wasn't hearing the quarry because it was lit up really well.

Why haven't I found any caves?

Comment: Punctuation, capitalization, and grammar are our very best friends.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like an answerable question; you just got unlucky and didn't hit any caves. It happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not playing on a customized world, then what you experienced is just the randomness of the world generator - it is not your personal fault or a bug ^^ It is by the way not unlikely to hear cave noises from caves above, maybe that is what you heard.

Answer (score -2):

Execute `/locate Mineshaft` and tp to the cords it gives you

Example :
`/locate Mineshaft`

**Located Mineshaft At 488 (y?) -56**

`/tp 488 ~100 -56`

If commands are not enabled, try using F3+Shift to activate the pie to locate a cave.

Comment: Mineshafts and caves are very different things